# How do you remove the ability for a user to make a comment or post on a page?

Tags: comments

I am building a new website on Wordpress, and all my pages have the add comment box at the bottom. I wish fo rthis to be removed from pages such as Home, Contact Us, About etc etc, but want it to remain on the blogs and galleries.

I have read [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4092/how-to-remove-comment-section-from-page-only-not-from-posts-pages) but do not really understand what this means to do. is there an easier way to do it. I do not have [this option](http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1280/5179502796_b9e09c10ba.jpg) under Settings -> Discussions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want comments on posts, I would suggest that you not change the discussion options in the Settings section, but you can enable/disable comments on a per post or per page basis.

In the admin area, click to edit a page that you want to restrict comments from. Then, when you scroll down the page, you will see a section called 'Discussion' and you will have an option to disable comments or trackbacks. If you do not see 'Discussion', scroll to the very top of your page, click on 'Screen Options' and make sure that the checkbox next to 'Discussion' is checked.

Note: Depending on your theme. Your page might display 'Comments Closed', or something to that effect. If that happens and you want to remove that text, you might actually have to get your hands dirty and dig into your Pages template.

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the discussion box from the top, and didn't know that it was there.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a plugin for that: [How to disable comments for WordPress pages in any theme](http://wpengineer.com/2302/how-to-disable-comments-for-wordpress-pages-in-any-theme/).

It’s really simple: You just replace the `comments_template` with an empty file on pages.

Comment: sorry only started using wp this week, how would I do this?

Comment: It is explained in the article: You hook into `comments_template` and point to a file without any output.

Comment: sorry thats all jargon, problem solved now anyway.