# How do I turn comments off for pages, but not posts?

Tags: pages, comments

I want my pages to not have comments enabled by default, only my posts. Is this possible?

Comment: [How to disable comments for WordPress pages in any theme](http://wpengineer.com/2302/how-to-disable-comments-for-wordpress-pages-in-any-theme/).

Comment: @toscho An interesting idea - should be an answer instead.

Comment: @kaiser [I did that](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/37897/73). [Two times](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/55286/73).

Comment: @toscho In this case, just tell me where to move my answers and then close this question.

Comment: The other questions are either bad or not a duplicate. We leave it as it is for now.

Comment: Any progress on this question?

Answer (score 3):

## The Front-End Solution:

### Trick your templates

You could *fake* that comments are open for specific post types. The following code works for all templates, that wrap the comment form (or whatever comment related code/UI elements) inside a conditional [`comments_open()`](http://queryposts.com/function/comments_open/) check.

### The little magic

… wrapped up in a quick'n'small plugin.

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: Disable comments for post types
 * Author: Kaiser
 * Author URl: http://unserkaiser.com
 */

/**
 * Set comments open to FALSE for specific post types
 * 
 * @param  bool $open
 * @param  int  $post_id
 * @return bool $open
 */
function wpse63098_diable_comments( $open, $post_id )
{
    if ( ! $open )
        return $open;

    $curr_post = get_post( $post_id );
    if ( in_array(
         $curr_post->post_type
        ,array(
            'page'
            // Add other (custom) post types here
         )
    ) )
        return FALSE;

    return $open;
}
add_filter( 'comments_open', 'wpse63098_diable_comments', 20, 2 );
```

### How to use it

Just upload and enable the plugin in the administration. Now every time the template questions for something like…

```
if ( comments_open() )
{
    // show comment form or whatever
}
```

…the `comment_open()` function gets intercepted and spits out a `FALSE` for your post type (like for example pages). Then it simply skips whatever is wrapped in there and doesn't show comments.

Comment: In wordpress 4.6.1 this gives a warning: `Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpse63098_diable_comments() `

Answer (score 1):

## The Back-End Solution:

---

### Javascript to set the default to unchecked

When you got the "Discussion" Meta Box open, then both checkboxes (Comments & Pingbacks) will be set to the value from…

> Admin UI » Settings » Discussion » Discussion Settings » Default article settings » "All people to post comments on new articles"

### A plugin to change the defaults

As we can't simply set different values for different post types, we can rely on javascript (which won't work, if JS is turned off - for example in a screen reader).

Now the meta box offers a hook, where we can add this little javascript snippets.

```
 <?php
 /**
 * Plugin Name: Uncheck comments for post types
 * Author: Kaiser
 * Author URl: http://unserkaiser.com
 */

/**
 * Uncheck ping/comments open status checkboxes for specific post types
 * 
 * @param  object $post
 * @return void
 */

function wpse63098_disable_comments_cb( $post )
{
    if ( ! in_array( 
         $post->post_type
        ,array(
            'page'
            // Add other (custom) post types here
         )
    ))
        return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready( function($) )
    {
        // Comments
        if ( $( '#comment_status' ).is( ':checked' ) )
            $( '#comment_status' ).attr( 'checked', false );

        // Pings
        if ( $( '#ping_status' ).is( ':checked' ) )
            $( '#ping_status' ).attr( 'checked', false );
    }
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'post_comment_status_meta_box-options', 'wpse63098_disable_comments_cb' );
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but doesn't seem to work (I added an extra ')') so it would compile. I also added a <script> tag around the Javascript

Comment: @Casebash Added the script tags (thanks). Will test later and get back to you.

Answer (score -2):

You probably just need to show the widget for Discussion.

[image]

1 go to Edit a Page and
2 select the Screen Options.
3 Check the Discussions box
4. Close / hide screen options.
5. Scroll down you page and you'll see the new Discussion widget
6. uncheck Allow Comments

[edit ... i was going to show another image here ... but suddenly the upload failed]

Comment: This is how to hide show comments in the backend, but it doesn't remove it from the front-end.